# Not getting response with my routes from remote server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, socket.io

I have a node js app running okay locally[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMP3u.png) but when deployed on remote server it is not giving response of the request but only giving response for home page

Comment: you will need to share some piece of code, to debug or understand

Comment: It is giving error message in console of browser that Refernce error io not found . io is for socket.io. Previously I was defining it as when i was runing it locally const socket = io('http://54.189.70.25'). But now as it is on remote server so now what?  <script src="/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script> also for this